React native android expo https requests showing network error
i am a react js developer trying to make and deploy an react native app, using expo cli, i am pretty much done but expo eas cli android apk is showing network error , it is working in web version but it is not working with android apk, is there some fact that https requests are not allowed in native expo cli android apks?
I tried to update my packages, checking navigations and later realised https isnt allowed, i am using expo so custom prebuilds dont make sense

Could you provide the error log? Without it, we are unable to provide you a solution.

try adding this to the androidManifest.xml debug & main

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

eg.
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="28"
    ....    


If you're connecting to a remote host then please make sure your API is SSL certificates are correctly verified.
